# Change scss theme variables using node env variable on initial render

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, sass-loader

I have developed a react-redux project with a particular theme and I would like to make it configurable to work across different themes.I want to achieve this using env node variables.

I will run the project in terminal like

[image]

I have referred [here](https://itnext.io/sharing-variables-between-js-and-sass-using-webpack-sass-loader-713f51fa7fa0) and tried using `castToSass()` in `node-sass-utils`, but i failed.

Is it possible to change the sass variable using webpack or any other library